# What Asp.net core web app with EF required from Azure hosting

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

new to azure hosting services. 
say, I create an asp.netcore web app and web api which uses Entityframework.

This asp.netcore app has 3 components:
1) Normal Web app
2) Web Api 
3) EntityFramework

Since EntityFramework will create a Database, what kind of azure hosting plan I should subscribe.

**-- Update**

Above, this asp.net web has the above 3 components. The entityFramework will create Table and Database

Case 1: Create a web App in Azure portal

name this webApp : AzureMyApp

use Shared Service plan ( the cheapest with domain Support)

After uploading my asp.netcore web application to the AzureMyApp

I would like to know:

1) Will my entityFramework able to create table in database using this Shared service plan?

2) Will I be able to do CRUD and other query in this SHARED service plan?

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Hosting Plan has **nothing to do** with the app needing a **database**, since they are **2 separate Azure services** you will be using. You can have an app running in the Free or Shared hosting plan, running on a Premium SQL Database. Or have an Isolated Service Plan running against a Basic SQL Database.

You should be able to figure out, at least get a feel for, what the initial load of the application and database will be. You should start from there.

*Important*
You're not committing to the Service Plan you choose at the start. It's just to get started, scaling up or down is real easy and fast. So you shouldn't worry to much about the choice you make there.

As far as I'm concerned, you should:
**Start small, test often and scale when necessary.**

**EDIT:**
For more information on App Service Plans, see [Azure App Service plan overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview). Here's (very) brief summary when to choose what, based on [How to choose an Azure App Service Plan](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37772.how-to-choose-an-azure-app-service-plan.aspx):

**Free**
Use this plan for PoC & development purposes. Production scenarios to be avoided for sure as you don’t have neither SSL nor a custom domain support

**Shared**
Though this tier is one level ahead of free tier, it's suggested only for hosting basic apps where you don’t have any security or recovery options as this tier also doesn’t support SSL and also backups.

**Basic**
This is the starting level tier for your production workloads. You get a dedicated instances & with 99.95% SLA, SSL support to put your apps to real work. With multiple instances you also get your app load balanced.

**Standard**
This is a pure fit for your serious production apps with a IP based SSL support.

**Premium**
As the name suggests, use this for your premium/high intensive critical mission apps

There's a lot of information available, listing it all here wouldn't add much to the answer.

Comment: Shared and basic for test/Dev environment only while standard plan for Run producttion. what are the diff  and what they mean? Can I use either one for my Ecommerce App?I want to start small for my ecommerce app which requires SQL Db. basic plan have no support for SQL. I know I can scale up later but starting is already not easy to use. I can not even know which plan to choose . here the link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/windows/ please help what plan I need for my eCommerce App for Mobile phone.

Comment: What does it means Basic plan Price 0.075/hour? What service I used that is charged for this rate? or they charge 0.075x24 hrs ? When visitor view my app, is this chargeable? I need help to understand the Azure services. I never use it before and I wanted to understand it. It seems it has many services we need now and future.

Comment: @MilkBottle If you only start small site, I believe that you dont need to use Azure, shared hosting should be enough for you. If you want to use Azure, you need to use their calculator pricing first. As I know if you use SQL, the price will be quite expensive. As an alternative, you can take a look at asphostportal.com hosting plan. They also support .net core and SQL server.

Comment: @rickvdbosch, just update my question. please kindly advise under this circumstance.

Comment: @rickvdbosch, just update my question. please kindly advise under this circumstance.